# Why is my tinyMCE initialization failing?

Tags: tinymce

the variable in double brackets comes from a Jinja/Flask template
here is the value of that variable, it is string
`'<div id="item" >test</div>'`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('init', function (e) {
                editor.setContent("{{editor_content|safe}}");
            });
        },
        plugins: [
        'advlist autolink autoresize link image imagetools lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
        'save table directionality template paste codesample'
        ],
        imagetools_toolbar: "rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage imageoptions",
        toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo paste | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
        images_upload_url: '{{ url_for("imageuploader") }}',
        automatic_uploads: true,
        images_reuse_filename: false,
        images_upload_base_path: '/static/uploads',
        visualblocks_default_state: true,
        forced_root_block : 'p',
    });
</script>
```

My code fails, this is what the browser console shows

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

`{{editor_content|safe}}` instructs Jinja not to escape the code as it should be HTML

**Update**
More troubleshooting shows me that this is OK
`"<div id='test'>sdsdsd</div>"`
while this is not
`'<div id="test">sdsdsd</div>'`
How do I get around this because the source of the content of my editor uses `"` and not `'`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that inconsistent use of `"` in the initialization string is causing this issue
You should use `"` within tags for properties and you should use `'` when initializing the editor
editor.setContent(`'`{{editor_content|safe}}`'`);